# Flutter JIT compilation and dynamic widget tree

Tags: android, flutter, jit, firebase-remote-config

I am trying to get my head around the possibility of cutomising a Flutter app for specific segment of customer-base.

As I understand, if I use AOT compilation the app is pre-compiled for the specified architecture (iOS or Android). Flutter also supports JIT compilation on Android. Does that mean that I can change the widget tree dynamically after I release the app to play store (I am thinking about using something like Firebase Remote Config to get the widgets code   based on the customer segment)

Comment: "change the widget tree"? what you mean by that?

Comment: Can be lot if things but basically change the child widget(s) of a parent widget. Ex: Instead of a card show a table or an image.May be showing new input field or a new button. Basically changing the UI elements and functionality.

Comment: I don't see how it relates to jit/aot though... to do what you say simply call `setState` which rebuilds the widget tree - and this is up to you what you do inside `build` method

Comment: The difference is , this is customisation. A widget in the released app has to be replaced with a another based on customer requirement. We do not know the replacing widget until a customer(s) request it. We do not want to release apps per-customer either.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of possible widgets I'd suggest using Firebase Remote Config to "select" which one gets shown.

If the widget you want to display cam be anything, you can use one of the following packages to build your widget from a network request:

https://pub.dev/packages/rfw
https://pub.dev/packages/json_dynamic_widget